Display a PDF on browser without asking for password but ask for password when opening pdf after downloading
I have an application that displays PDFs in a web page and users can download them. I want to add user and owner passwords to the PDF, but with my code now it's asking for the user password before displaying on browser. I tried not adding the user password and that makes the pdf display on browser as normal, but it also does not ask for password when opened after being downloaded.
System.Text.ASCIIEncoding encoding = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding();
byte[] userpwd = encoding.GetBytes("Secretinfo");
byte[] ownerpwd = encoding.GetBytes("SecretinfoAdmin");
iTextSharp.text.Document pdfDoc = new iTextSharp.text.Document();
System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfCopy pdfCopy = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfCopy(pdfDoc, ms);
pdfCopy.SetEncryption(userpwd, ownerpwd, iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter.HideWindowUI | iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter.HideToolbar | iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter.HideMenubar | iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter.ALLOW_PRINTING, iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter.STANDARD_ENCRYPTION_128);
iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader pdfReader = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader(ra, null);
int pages = pdfReader.NumberOfPages;
                
pdfDoc.Open();
int i = 0;
while (i < pages)
{
    pdfCopy.AddPage(pdfCopy.GetImportedPage(pdfReader, i + 1));
    i += 1;
}
pdfDoc.Close();

Byte[] byteInfo = ms.ToArray();
Response.Clear();
Response.ClearContent();
Response.ClearHeaders();
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"; //octet-stream
Response.AddHeader("content-length", byteInfo.Length.ToString());
Response.BinaryWrite(byteInfo);
Response.Flush();
Response.End();

How do I apply user and owner passwords to my PDF for when they're downloaded without them asking for the user password when being displayed on the web page?

How do you display this PDF?

@Justinas I edited my post. Is that what you mean?

Maybe just work without a password protected pdf, and add an separate link on your page where they can download a password protected version, which they need to set upon downloading.

Does this answer your question? How to programatically open a PDF with a User password
